# How to set the value of a usercontrol's property in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

There are 3 dropdownlists that are being used at several places. So I decided to put them in a userControl.

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="DetailsDropDownList.ascx.vb"
    Inherits="UserControls_DetailsDropDownList" %>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="dedMoth" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dedDay" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dedYear" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In the Code behind, I've defined a property so that I capture the value to display.

```
public DateTime DetailsDate { get; set; }
```

So I'm setting the property this way: `myUserControl.DetailsDate = myObject.myDate`

The problem is that no value is being set. When I set the breakpoint, I notice that UserControl's life cycle starts after that of the main page.

I've tried this as well but no luck.

```
<uc1:DetailsDropDownList runat="server" ID="myUserControl" 
     DetailsDate ="<%= myObject.myDate%>" />
```

So How do I set the value of a UserControl?

Comment: Look like the value is set very early in the life cycle. Could you set the value inside **Page_Load** and see it works?

Comment: Which page load, the main page's or the usecontrol's?

Comment: Presumably, the main page is calling `myUserControl.DetailsDate = myObject.myDate` so it should be in the Page's `Page_Load` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist your property. If you don't it's reset each and every single time the page loads, just like any other local variable. You can easily persist into viewstate though like so:

```
public DateTime DetailsDate
{
     get{
         if(ViewState["DetailsDate"] == null)
         {
              return DateTime.Today;
         }
         else
         {
              return (DateTime)ViewState["DetailsDate"];
         }
     }
     set {ViewState["DetailsDate"] = value;}
}
```

Comment: I've put a breakpoint in the above code. However, the problem is that when this line `myUserControl.DetailsDate = myObject.myDate` is executed, the above code is not being hit.

Answer (score 1):

Add Page.DataBind(); in Page_Load() event. This will bind page data. Once debugger pass through page load check expected date is coming or not.